# Trying to call a javascript function with variable from ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, function

I have a simple text field that looks like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onblur="checkMyText()"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

At the top of my page, I have this little bit of JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkMyText() {
        var args = document.getElementById('<% =txtMyTextBox.ClientId %>').value;
        alert(args);
        }
</script>
```

*This works fine*. When I try to do this.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onblur="checkMyText("txtMyTextBox")"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

.
.
.

```
 function checkMyText(ElementID) {
                var args =  document.getElementById('<% =ElementID.ClientId %>').value;
                alert(args)
                }
```

It fails.

I am entirely new to javascript, so I am not sure how it handles passing variables or treating them inside strings. The idea is if I add an: ID="txtMyOtherTextBox" I only need to call onblur="checkMyText("txtMyOtherTextBox")" for that button. How do I javascript strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this line

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" 
      onblur="checkMyText("txtMyTextBox")"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

you have two main errors.

1. wrong quotas -> `"checkMyText("txtMyTextBox")"`
2. you pass the ID as you see it on code behind, not as its rendered on page.

Usually we pass the current element to a JavaScript function using the `this` keyword. Eg:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onblur="checkMyText(this)"/>

function checkMyText(me) {
                var args =  me.value;
                alert(args)
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the ClientId of the Textbox to the javacscript function. You cannot use server side code while you are executing Javascript (which you are trying to do by calling `ElementID.ClientId` in your js function.

Determine the ClientId while still on the server and put it as a string in the function call: `onblur="checkMyText('<%=txtMyTextBox.ClientId %>')"` Then you can work with the id in the javascript function.

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onblur="checkMyText('<%=txtMyTextBox.ClientId %>')"></asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkMyText(id) {
        var args = document.getElementById(id).value;
        alert(args);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your page source, you'll see that ASP.NET mangles your nice readable ID's in the interest of keeping things truly unique in the case of using the same "control" multiple times per page (e.g. a News Widget or something)

I do not like that aspect of ASP.NET and prefer to manually manage my ID's (and use classes where useful), so I use `ClientIDMode="Static"` in my Page Directive. This directs ASP.NET to use your ID's as you specified them in your source code, enabling you to do exactly as you depict in your second example that (currently) doesn't work.

That said [Aristos'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117766/622129) answer is the preferred solution